# moment(aDate).utcOffset(aDate).format() method is stripping date like +00:00Z

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

When I invoke

```
moment("2001-09-11T00:00:00+00:00").utcOffset("2001-09-11T00:00:00+00:00").format()
```

"2001-09-11T00:00:00Z" gets returned.  Is there any way to have `+00:00` displayed instead of `Z`?

```js
console.log(moment("2001-09-11T00:00:00+00:00").utcOffset("2001-09-11T00:00:00+00:00").format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: That's the default the `format` method produces. If you want to change that to affect all places where this method gets called without any parameters - then change the default format. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: like said bay CBroe this is the dafault formatting output of moment, if you want you can specify a string with the format you desire. In your case is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`